# I was writing script to player object that change the material. it works but the move of the player gets lost when I use the script

Tags: c#, game-development

I made a 2D unity game.  I was writing script to player object that change the material by clicking the mouse button. it works but the move of the player gets lost when I use the script, and specifically when I press "A"(when the player go to left)

I was writing script to player object that change the material by clicking the mouse button.
that is the script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class ChangeColour : MonoBehaviour
{
   int i ;
   int b ;
   public Material Material1;
   public Material Material2;
   
     public GameObject Object;
 
     private void LateUpdate() 
        
        {
        
         if(Input.GetButtonDown("Blue"))
         {
          Object.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = Material1;
         }
         
         else if(Input.GetButtonDown("Red"))
         {
           Object.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = Material2;
         }
         
        }
     
 
}
```

player movement script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

public CharacterController2D controller;

public float runSpeed = 40f;

float horizontalMove = 0f;
bool jump = false;
bool crouch = false;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        jump = true;
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))
    {
        crouch = true;
    } else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch"))
    {
        crouch = false;
    }

}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    // Move our character
    controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, crouch, jump);
    jump = false;
}
```

}

character controller srcipt

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class CharacterController2D : MonoBehaviour{

[SerializeField] private float m_JumpForce = 400f;                          // Amount of force added when the player jumps.
[Range(0, 1)] [SerializeField] private float m_CrouchSpeed = .36f;          // Amount of maxSpeed applied to crouching movement. 1 = 100%
[Range(0, .3f)] [SerializeField] private float m_MovementSmoothing = .05f;  // How much to smooth out the movement
[SerializeField] private bool m_AirControl = false;                         // Whether or not a player can steer while jumping;
[SerializeField] private LayerMask m_WhatIsGround;                          // A mask determining what is ground to the character
[SerializeField] private Transform m_GroundCheck;                           // A position marking where to check if the player is grounded.
[SerializeField] private Transform m_CeilingCheck;                          // A position marking where to check for ceilings
[SerializeField] private Collider2D m_CrouchDisableCollider;                // A collider that will be disabled when crouching

const float k_GroundedRadius = .2f; // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if grounded
private bool m_Grounded;            // Whether or not the player is grounded.
const float k_CeilingRadius = .2f; // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if the player can stand up
private Rigidbody2D m_Rigidbody2D;
private bool m_FacingRight = true;  // For determining which way the player is currently facing.
private Vector3 m_Velocity = Vector3.zero;

[Header("Events")]
[Space]

public UnityEvent OnLandEvent;

[System.Serializable]
public class BoolEvent : UnityEvent<bool> { }

public BoolEvent OnCrouchEvent;
private bool m_wasCrouching = false;

private void Awake()
{
    m_Rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    if (OnLandEvent == null)
        OnLandEvent = new UnityEvent();

    if (OnCrouchEvent == null)
        OnCrouchEvent = new BoolEvent();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    bool wasGrounded = m_Grounded;
    m_Grounded = false;

    // The player is grounded if a circlecast to the groundcheck position hits anything designated as ground
    // This can be done using layers instead but Sample Assets will not overwrite your project settings.
    Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(m_GroundCheck.position, k_GroundedRadius, m_WhatIsGround);
    for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
    {
        if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
        {
            m_Grounded = true;
            if (!wasGrounded)
                OnLandEvent.Invoke();
        }
    }
}


public void Move(float move, bool crouch, bool jump)
{
    // If crouching, check to see if the character can stand up
    if (!crouch)
    {
        // If the character has a ceiling preventing them from standing up, keep them crouching
        if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(m_CeilingCheck.position, k_CeilingRadius, m_WhatIsGround))
        {
            crouch = true;
        }
    }

    //only control the player if grounded or airControl is turned on
    if (m_Grounded || m_AirControl)
    {

        // If crouching
        if (crouch)
        {
            if (!m_wasCrouching)
            {
                m_wasCrouching = true;
                OnCrouchEvent.Invoke(true);
            }

            // Reduce the speed by the crouchSpeed multiplier
            move *= m_CrouchSpeed;

            // Disable one of the colliders when crouching
            if (m_CrouchDisableCollider != null)
                m_CrouchDisableCollider.enabled = false;
        } else
        {
            // Enable the collider when not crouching
            if (m_CrouchDisableCollider != null)
                m_CrouchDisableCollider.enabled = true;

            if (m_wasCrouching)
            {
                m_wasCrouching = false;
                OnCrouchEvent.Invoke(false);
            }
        }

        // Move the character by finding the target velocity
        Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector2(move * 10f, m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
        // And then smoothing it out and applying it to the character
        m_Rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector3.SmoothDamp(m_Rigidbody2D.velocity, targetVelocity, ref m_Velocity, m_MovementSmoothing);

        // If the input is moving the player right and the player is facing left...
        if (move > 0 && !m_FacingRight)
        {
            // ... flip the player.
            Flip();
        }
        // Otherwise if the input is moving the player left and the player is facing right...
        else if (move < 0 && m_FacingRight)
        {
            // ... flip the player.
            Flip();
        }
    }
    // If the player should jump...
    if (m_Grounded && jump)
    {
        // Add a vertical force to the player.
        m_Grounded = false;
        m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, m_JumpForce));
    }
}


private void Flip()
{
    // Switch the way the player is labelled as facing.
    m_FacingRight = !m_FacingRight;

    // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1.
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;
}
```

}`

Comment: Can you please share the code where you handle the movement of the player?

Comment: Also a quick tip, do not use every time the "GetComponent<Renderer>()" method because is heavy enough. What you can do is instead of keeping a reference of the GameObject you can directly use the "Renderer" component of the gameobject and simply drag and drop it, or you can keep your GameObject reference and create a reference of the "Renderer" component and on the "Start()" method you can use the "renderer = Object.GetComponent<Renderer> ()" and then use the "renderer.material".

Comment: You would need to share the movement script so that we can see what is happening over there. I would also take Pavlos's advice on assigning the renderer through inspector or calling "GetComponent<>()" once in the start function to assign it. -- You said that there is specifically a problem with the "A" button. Have you tried going to Edit > Project Settings > Input Manager to see how your buttons/names are set up? Maybe some of the buttons you have set up (Blue & Red) are also connected to some of your movement buttons.

Comment: I use a code from internet. it contains two codes.  one called player movement and the last called character controller.

Comment: I post the scripts.

Comment: @PavlosMavris  I put the script